# Ubuntu Trusty Preseed Error

Tags: ubuntu, init-script, sysvinit, lsb, preseed

I have a preseed file that installs Trusty but the install is giving me this error:

```
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: Setting up sysv-rc (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: info: Reordering boot system, log to        
/var/lib/insserv/run-20140722T1052.log
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: error: Something failed while migrating.
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: error: Unable to migrate to dependency based boot     
sequencing.
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: See  
http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot for
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: more information about dependency based boot  
sequencing. To
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: reattempt the migration process run 'dpkg --
configure sysv-rc'.
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: dpkg: error processing package sysv-rc (-- 
configure):
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target:  subprocess installed post-installation script  
returned error exit status 1
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: Errors were encountered while processing:
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target:  sysv-rc
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: E
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: : 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code 
(1)
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: 
Jul 22 17:52:42 in-target: Setting up sysv-rc (2.88dsf-41+deb7u1) ...
Jul 22 17:52:42 main-menu[219]: WARNING **: Configuring 'pkgsel' failed with  
error code 100
Jul 22 17:52:42 main-menu[219]: WARNING **: Menu item 'pkgsel' failed.
Jul 22 17:52:56 main-menu[219]: INFO: Modifying debconf priority limit from    
'high' to 'medium'
Jul 22 17:52:56 debconf: Setting debconf/priority to medium
Jul 22 17:52:59 main-menu[219]: INFO: Menu item 'save-logs' selected
```

Seems to me that 'something failed' is very vague. Does anyone have any idea what could have happened? I tried going into a shell and doing the `dpkg --configure sysv-rc` but dpkg isn't installed at that point I guess. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you run `chroot /target` before running `dpkg --reconfigure sysv-rc`?

Comment: @JosephR. Says that sysv-rc is already installed and configured :/ Reconfigure is not an available option.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `dpkg --configure sysv-rc`.

Comment: @JosephR.Yea I figured, gives me "Package sysv-rc is already installed and configured - Errors were encountered while processing: sysv-rc"

Comment: Did you check the log file it's referring to? `/var/lib/insserv/run-20140722T1052.log` (most probably it will still be `/target/var/lig/insserv/...`)

Comment: @JosephR. Yea just found out that it can't find 'insserv' because it's not in the right PATH. I guess I just have to figure out how to add a new PATH to preseed